# Difference between accelerometer and vibrometer

Tags: accelerometer

I'm trying to understand the difference between an accelerometer and a vibrometer. That is, from the name I can imagine that one is used to measure accelerations and the other vibrations, but if I take the datasheets they both look like accelerometers, they have the same type of operation, structure, type of communication and available data.

Is it correct to say that a vibrometer is just an accelerometer with a higher sampling rate? or are there other differences?

Comment: What is the difference between a ruler and a measuring stick? If the data sheets say the same things then it just has two names...

Comment: Will you vibrometer tell you in which direction and with what acceleration the vibration is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accelerometers are usually a 3-dimensional (X,Y,Z) measurement device for determining things like orientation, or the instantaneous acceleration. Vibrometers are typically used to measure the frequency of vibrations in a single dimension.